# Many compatibility problems with gluonts

Tags: python, installation, pycharm, anaconda

I would like to install the gluonts package. The problem here is that there are extremely many compatibility issues. I cannot manually solve each of these compatibility problems by trial and error. Is there a general way to solve the whole thing automatically?

I am working in the PyCharm environment with Pyton. to use a virtual environment I am using Anaconda.

The packages I need in any case are Jupyter, Numpy, Pandas, mxnet, matplotlib and just glounts.

I have also tried to install the whole thing in a different order, that didn't work either, so I installed gluonts first, which also worked, but when I then wanted to install mxnet is then the problem.
Since I'm writing my bachelor thesis and accordingly under time pressure, I would be very grateful for your help.

My plan is to implement the whole thing in Pyton 3.6, I've also tried switching to Pyton 3.7, but that didn't help either. Now I will try it with Python 3.5.

When solving the problem, it should be noted that I am not completely free in my way of working, since I work on a unicomputer and do not have all the rights, etc.
**EDIT**
So I have now found a solution myself, how to use everything reasonably.
You create with anaconda prompt a new environment and use there Python 3.9 , when creating give the following code
conda create -n env python=3.9 numpy=1.16.6
conda activate env
pip install mxnet gluonts jupyter
conda deactivate

now you could select this as normal environment in PyCharm. You could also look at the whole thing normally in the anaconda navigator and see which packages you have on it.

Answer (score 0):

The general form is:

```py
pip install gluonts
```

You should try this:

```py
# support for mxnet models, faster datasets
pip install gluonts[mxnet,pro]  

# support for torch models, faster datasets
pip install gluonts[torch,pro]
```

and then try this example:

```py
from gluonts.dataset.util import to_pandas
from gluonts.dataset.pandas import PandasDataset
from gluonts.dataset.repository.datasets import get_dataset
from gluonts.model.deepar import DeepAREstimator
from gluonts.mx import Trainer

dataset = get_dataset("airpassengers")

deepar = DeepAREstimator(prediction_length=12, freq="M", trainer=Trainer(epochs=5))
model = deepar.train(dataset.train)

# Make predictions
true_values = to_pandas(list(dataset.test)[0])
true_values.to_timestamp().plot(color="k")

prediction_input = PandasDataset([true_values[:-36], true_values[:-24], true_values[:-12]])
predictions = model.predict(prediction_input)

for color, prediction in zip(["green", "blue", "purple"], predictions):
    prediction.plot(color=f"tab:{color}")

plt.legend(["True values"], loc="upper left", fontsize="xx-large")
```

Here is the link to the gluonts 0.10.2 module:

https://pypi.org/project/gluonts/

Please state any errors that you see with this.

Comment: Okay thanks, at the point nochmla 2 questions. So I install the package mxnet then not "manually", but only in the dependency to glounts?

Comment: I use anaconda as interpreter, my supervisor told me that installing packages there is not about pip install, do you happen to know how to do that with it? Do you know how to make the latest gluonts version available to me then so that I can use the whole thing? If I want to install gluonts in PyCharm via Interpreter Settings or also via the Anaconda.Navigator, a maximum of 0.8. something is suggested to me and I can also not use a newer version.

Comment: One more question, not directly related to the problem, but if ic already have a person here who knows something about it, do you think it's a big project using deepAr to make a prediction for multiple time series with multiple variables?

Comment: following the proper install protool will avoid trial and error effects. but more importantly, will let you verify [1] that the package is installed correctly and [2] confirm that it works (or not). If it did not work at this point, you could then troubleshoot the error via the error messages given...  so in summary, i would initially follow the procedure as given.